# Rest Api for MS Access?

Tags: api, rest, ms-access

I currently have an existing MS Access database. I need to create an app to view or edit it on the go.

Is there anyway I can create a REST API or anything similar for an existing MS Access database that I can make HTTP Requests through an app or website?

Answer (score 0):

Yes You Can Do That and you have a many options

1. Java EE , With java EE you can make a restful api on any database with servlet or with spring freamwork
2. PHP , with php you can make a rest api with any database too [LINK](https://docs.phalconphp.com/en/latest/reference/tutorial-rest.html)
3. asp.net , also with asp.net you can make an api for database [LINK](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/older-versions/build-restful-apis-with-aspnet-web-api)
4. nodejs , with nodejs you can make an api on this database use this module [LINK](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mssql-api)

note : the first thing you need it to make any api on any database must get the concept of restful api and every thing will be easy

Comment: The poster is looking for an automated tool that will read a database and generate an API based on the tables and fields found in it.  (As I am too).  As an example... https://github.com/o1lab/xmysql